# How to get key and value from a js map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a custom grid in jquery so took a look at jquery plugin development. In it I assigned headers for the grid and want to assign rows, but need help with assigning values to rows.

```
var headers=new Array();
headers=["Name","Host Name","Description","Type","Last Update Time"];
```

I thought of creating a array of maps like below, which will get assigned as rows in my grid, but need help in understanding how to assign. Similar to `headers` these rows can be generic.

```
var myrows = [
                {cfgid:0, name:"Lukas Arts",host:"baxton", description:"test",type:"Dev",updateDate:"Thu Apr 26 04:31:10 IST 2012"},
                {cfgid:1, name:"Adiga",host:"beetle", description:"test",type:"Dev",updateDate:"Fri Apr 27 07:21:43 IST 2012"},
                {cfgid:2, name:"Max Miller",host:"barry", description:"test",type:"Dev",updateDate:"Mon Apr 16 04:11:40 IST 2012"}
                ];
```

This is the code

```
jQuery.fn.abcGrid = function (tableid, heading, data, options) {
    abcoptions = jQuery.extend ({
    tableCss: "tableForms",
    tableHeaderCss: "tableHeading",
    label: "Informatica CSM",
    header: heading,
    rows: data
    }, options);

    var ele_table='';
    var ele_table_start='<table id="'+abcoptions.tableid+'" class="'+abcoptions.tableCss+'"><tbody>';
    var ele_table_end='</tbody></table>';
    var ele_table_header='';
    var ele_table_row='';

    var tempHeader='';
    var tempRow='';

    /*Table header creation*/
    for(var i=0;i<abcoptions.header.length;i++)
        tempHeader+='<td class="'+abcoptions.tableHeaderCss+'">'+abcoptions.header[i]+'</th>';
    ele_table_header='<tr>'+tempHeader+'</tr>';

    ele_table=ele_table_start+ele_table_header+ele_table_end;
    $(this).html(ele_table);
    //it creates only headers properly
};
```

I call this code as

```
$('#updateDiv').abcGrid("tabel1", headers, myrows);
```

Comment: Why do you assign a new `Array()` to `headers`, when you overwrite it with a new array on the next line?  Just do `var headers = ["Name","Host Name","Description","Type","Last Update Time"];`

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of an item in the map, you could do:

```
abcoptions.rows[i].cfgid
```

The `rows[i]` is your map -- you can place the key after the dot, or `rows[i]['cfgid']`

-- Edit: renamed `header` to `rows`.

Comment: "The `header[i]` is your map" I think you mean `myrows`